# How to retrieve only less than given value from table column with SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have to make query to just only returns rows if balance get less than 500. but still got all rows of the SQL table.

Here is my query :

```
SELECT  
    a.[ID], a.[strUserName],
    (SELECT intCurrentBalance 
     FROM accountmappings 
     WHERE intUserID = a.[ID] AND intAccountType = 1 
       AND (intCurrentBalance < 500 AND intCurrentBalance IS NOT NULL)) AS Prm_Balance,
    (SELECT intCurrentBalance 
     FROM accountmappings 
     WHERE intUserID = a.[ID] AND intAccountType = 2 
       AND (intCurrentBalance < 500 AND intCurrentBalance IS NOT NULL)) AS Trn_Balance,
    (SELECT intCurrentBalance 
     FROM accountmappings 
     WHERE intUserID = a.[ID] AND intAccountType = 3 
       AND (intCurrentBalance < 500 AND intCurrentBalance IS NOT NULL)) AS Opt_Balance,
    a.[strMobile],
    a.[strEmailID], 
    a.[bIsApproved],
    a.[bIsActive],
    a.[dtlastrecharge],
    CASE WHEN b.id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE b.id END AS createdbyId,
    CASE WHEN b.strusername IS NULL THEN '' ELSE b.strusername END AS createdby
FROM 
    users a 
LEFT JOIN
    users b ON a.intCreatedBy = b.ID
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: Your query is supposed to return all rows (It has no `where` clause.), only the correlated subqueries check for balances less than 500. Those subqueries will return `NULL` if a suitable value isn't found. Tip: Use table aliases in subqueries and apply them to all column references.

Comment: @HABO -can u please explain with some code...

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  a.[ID] ,a.[strUserName],
             (CASE WHEN CB.intAccountType = 1 THEN CB.intCurrentBalance else 0) as Prm_Balance
            ,(CASE WHEN CB.intAccountType = 2 THEN CB.intCurrentBalance else 0) as Trn_Balance
            ,(CASE WHEN CB.intAccountType = 3 THEN CB.intCurrentBalance else 0) as Opt_Balance
            ,a.[strMobile]
            ,a.[strEmailID]
            ,a.[bIsApproved]
            ,a.[bIsActive]
            ,a.[dtlastrecharge]
            ,case when b.id is null then 0 else b.id end as createdbyId
            ,case when b.strusername is null then '' else b.strusername end as createdby
             FROM users a 
             left join users b on a.intCreatedBy = b.ID
             inner join intCurrentBalance CB on intUserID = a.[ID] and (CB.intCurrentBalance IS NOT NULL and CB.intCurrentBalance < 500)
```

Comment: what is CB I can't understand...

Comment: @shalingajjar **CB** is object of **intCurrentBalance** table